# Does a laptop antenna need to be marked as “6Ghz” to work with a WiFi 6E card?

Tags: laptop, wifi, upgrade, bluetooth-5, antennas

I bought a new Wi-Fi card for my laptop. The card has Wi-Fi 6E and Bluetooth 5. I need to also replace the old 1x1 antenna with a 2x2 antenna.

However, I can't seem to find any internal laptop antennas for sale that are marked as Wi-Fi 6E.

I found a lot of antennas that were marked as 2.4GHz and 5GHz, but none that were marked as 6GHz. (Wi-Fi 6E uses the 6GHz band, right?)

- Does the antenna actually need to be marked as 6GHz, or will any 2x2 antenna work with a Wi-Fi 6E card?
- Similarly, do I need to look for anything special to make sure that the antenna will support the Bluetooth 5 functionality of the card?
- Does anyone have any recommendations for an appropriate antenna?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, you would need a 6Ghz antenna for WiFi 6E.
- WiFi starts at 2.4Ghz, Bluetooth starts at 2.45Ghz, meaning that a WiFi antenna should do both, unless the card or computer needs them separate
- Here is a 2.4Ghz to 6Ghz antenna: [Link To 6hz antenna](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/EMF2471A3S-10MH4L/776-EMF2471A3S-10MH4L-ND/13910448?curr=usd&utm_campaign=buynow&utm_medium=aggregator&utm_source=octopart)

Here is a link to a Bluetooth antenna, only needed if the card or computer needs separate antennas: [Link to Bluetooth antenna](https://www.digikey.com.au/en/products/detail/pulse-electronics/W3334B0100/15287059)